# Show data in UIPickerView second component based on first component selection

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am using a picker with two components. I want if I select a row in first component on the basis of selected component it shows the value of the corresponding data.

[image]

As Picker is showing that England has corresponding clubs when England is selected. I want to do same for the other countries. But I am not getting which approach to follow.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
{

    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{

    if(component ==0)
    {
        return [Nations count];
    }

    else{
        if(country_flag==0)
        {
        return [England count];
        }
        else if (country_flag==1)
        {
            return [Espana count];
        }
        else if (country_flag==2)
        {
            return [Netherlands count];
        }
        else if (country_flag==3)
        {
            return [Germany count];
        }
        else if (country_flag==4)
        {
            return [Italy count];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component ==0)
    {
        return [Nations objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    else{
        if(country_flag==0)
        {
            return [England objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else if (country_flag==1)
        {
            return [Espana objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else if (country_flag==2)
        {
            return [Netherlands objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else if (country_flag==3)
        {
            return [Germany objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else if (country_flag==4)
        {
            return [Italy objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    label.text=[Nations objectAtIndex:row];

    str = [[NSString alloc]init];

    if (country_flag==0) {
        str=@"England";
        label_1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
        NSLog(@"%@",label_1);
        str=@"";
        country_flag =1;
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
    else if (country_flag==1)
    {
        str=@"Espana";
        label_1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
        NSLog(@"%@",label_1);
        str=@"";
        country_flag =2;
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
    else if (country_flag==2)
    {
        str=@"Netherlands";
        label_1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
        NSLog(@"%@",label_1);
        str=@"";
        country_flag =3;
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
    else if (country_flag==3)
    {
        str=@"Germany";
        label_1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
        NSLog(@"%@",label_1);
        str=@"";
        country_flag =4;
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
    else if (country_flag==4)
    {
        str=@"Germany";
        label_1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
        NSLog(@"%@",label_1);
        str=@"";
      //  country_flag =4;
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the data

```
Nations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"England",@"Espana",@"Germany",@"Netherlands",@"Germany",@"Italy", nil];

    England=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Arsenal",@"Chelsea",@"Manchester City",@"Manchester United",@"Liverpool",@"Tottenham",@"Fulham City",@"Stoke City",@"Sunderland",@"NewCastle United",@"Blackburn Rovers",@"Southampton",@"Wolvers",@"Aston Villa", nil];

    Espana = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Barcelona",@"Real Madrid",@"Valencia",@"Athletico Madrid",@"Athletico Balbao",@"Getafe CF",@"Sevilla CF", nil];

    Netherlands = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Celtics",@"Ajax",@"Amesterdam", nil];

    Germany = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bayern Munich",@"Bermen",@"Fiorentina",@"Pampas",@"Nord", nil];

    Italy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"AC Milan",@"Inter Milan",@"Juventus", nil];
```

Comment: try  *[picker reloadComponent:(NSInteger)component]*; instead of      *[picker reloadAllComponents]*;

Comment: Thanks for your support man but no change.

Comment: There's something weird with your country_flag variable.  Can you show us where it's declared?  Also, why must country_flag == 1 before I can choose Espana?

Comment: I have declared country_flag=0 but I am trying to increase flag value in didSelectRow delegate.
I know I am making a mess with flags guide me a correct code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your code.. with minor modifications..

didSelectRow

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == 0) {
        club=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@" , [Nations objectAtIndex:row]];
        [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
          }
```

}

after that...

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(component ==0)
    {
        return [Nations count];
    }
    else {
        if ([club isEqualToString:@"Espana"]) {
            return [Espana count];
        }
        if ([club isEqualToString:@"Germany"]) {
            return [Germany count];
        }
        // if...
       else  {
            return [England count];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component ==0)
    {
        return [Nations objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        if ([club isEqualToString:@"Espana"]) {
            return [Espana objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        if ([club isEqualToString:@"Germany"]) {
            return [Germany objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        //if....
      else  {
            return [England objectAtIndex:row];


        }
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

**UPD**

in h file I have

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *arrayColors;
    NSMutableArray *Nations;
    NSMutableArray *England;
    NSMutableArray *Espana;
    NSMutableArray *Germany;
    NSString *club;
}
```

after that.. you must connect de pickerView to yours ViewController (dataSource and delegate)
[image]

Comment: doesn't make any change...still not getting the club names for other countries except England.

Comment: for improvement.. you can add in viewDidLoad ->  club=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"England"];

Comment: Okay...I have one question that why are you using Storyboard?

Comment: Just because: "Storyboards allow you to map out, visually, all of the views in your applications and how they interrelate", because is more easy to code :)

Comment: @DeepakKhiwani But I think you are right my comment are useless said like that I remove them

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, i think it can help you

1. First of all make sure that you have connected your picker with
   IBOutlet .
2. Still if you get the issue you can use

`[thePickerView reloadComponent:(NSInteger)component];`

instead of

```
[picker reloadComponent:(NSInteger)component];
```

Comment: [picker reloadComponent:(NSInteger)component];  is not working 
I am getting data only on England. I am unable to get for other countries. The data on the right side (Arsenal....) remains same even if I roll the Countries.

Comment: check the values in your other country array like Espana and others and make sure that they do not have the same values.

Comment: I have posted my data...take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do it like that.
You create a plist file containing the data of all your countries
the result is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>England</key>
    <array>
        <string>Chelsea</string>
        <string>Arsenal</string>
    </array>
    <key>Spain</key>
    <array>
        <string>Barca</string>
        <string>Real</string>
    </array>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

assuming the following are defined in the properties or somewhere

```
NSDictionary *countryClubs;
NSArray *countries;
NSArray *clubs;
```

you then do things like that

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *plistFile = [bundle URLForResource:@"myPListFile" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistFile];
    self.countryClubs = dictionary;

    NSString *selectedCountry = [self.countries objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [countryClubs objectForKey:selectedCountry];
    self.clubs = array;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0)
        return [self.countries count];
    return [self.clubs count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0)
        return [self.countries objectAtIndex:row];
    return [self.clubs objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
       if (component == 0) {
         NSString *selectedCountry = [self.countries objectAtIndex:row];
         NSArray *array = [countryClubs objectForKey:selectedCountry];
         self.clubs = array;
         [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
         [picker reloadComponent:1];
    }
}
```

This should help you. I hope there is not to much typo mistakes but you should at least get the general idea.

Comment: Going with your approach, should I delete my arrays containing country names and club names?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean be "delete my arrays". As my example shows usually you have a global dictionary with all the data with country as keys and the resulting clubs as subarrays. Then for your picker you keep 2 arrays for the data. 1 for the countries, that you don't delete/reload, and 1 for the clubs that is refreshed/changed each time you change the country.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `didSelectRow` method.  You check which country is already selected (in `country_flag`) before allowing the selection of a new country.  I don't think there's any reason to do this.

Allow any country to be selected.  Then set `country_flag` based on the row that was selected.

Just do `country_flag = row+1;`

You can then have your `if` statements to set up your label if that's important.