# Reading value from selected row in picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i have created picker in Xcode with 3 columns, 2. and 3. column are filled with data based on the data in first column. It works fine, and data is displaying correctly, my only problem is how can i write value  that is currently displaying ing selected row for 2. and 3. column to some string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use -`[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:]` to determine which row is selected, and then return the object at that index within your data array.

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

   NSInteger selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selectedPickerRow=[yourArrayOfElements objectAtIndex:selectedRow];


    // Handle the selection
}
```

Comment: but my "yourArrayOfElements" is always changing, for example, if my first column is selected on "distance", my 2. and 3. columns are filled with array "distanceMeasuers" that has meters, kilometers etc. if my first column is "mass", my 2. and 3. column is filled with array "massMeasures" that has kg, tone etc.

Comment: When the value of your picker is changed try to invoke  `[pickerView reloadComponent:numberOfComponent]; 
But I never test it before. Please read this hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493402/show-data-in-uipickerview-second-component-based-on-first-component-selection

Comment: Thanks, i will look into that. That link also helped me in displaying data for separate columns earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `didSelectRow` delegate

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithString: cell.textLabel.text];


   NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row+1 inSection:0];
   UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];
   NSString *cell1Text = [NSString stringWithString: cell1.textLabel.text];

   NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row+2 inSection:indexPath.section];
   UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath2];
   NSString *cell2Text = [NSString stringWithString: cell2.textLabel.text];

}
```

Comment: i have that, but that reads only from first column in picker, i need to read from 2. and 3. column in picker in which those columns have different values based on 1. column

Comment: Thanks for answer, what do u have to add also beside this code? Implement something? Add some properties? I am a merely beginner so excuse my stupid questions. When i add that code it says that property tableView not found on object of type "ConverterViewController"

Comment: Can u please help me with this?