# How to display content of selected row in 2. column in picker

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have picker with 3. columns which are populated by few different arrays. 2. and 3. column are populated depending on selected row in 1. column. My question is how to display selected row in 2. and 3. column on a label.

I can't use `self.selectedRow=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@" , [self.myArray1 objectAtIndex:row]];`

because myArray1 is always changing, sometime second column is populated with myArray2, myArray3 etc.

Comment: This is the similar problem to Your : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148280/reading-value-from-selected-row-in-picker/21148486#21148486

Comment: Yes, but yourArrayOfElements is always changing because i have multiple arrays and 2. column is filled with different ones at different occasions.

Comment: Please read coments under this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21148486/3186896