# Multiple pickerviews and retrieving data from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uipickerview

I have 4 pickerview in a view controller and, I need that after 2 of them have been selected with the desired user preference I want the third to retrieve data from Parse based on the user's selection of the other two, any way I can implement this? Now I've each picker view with a tag but I can't implement a PFQuery inside the pickerview methods.

Thank you.

This is what I have, trying to do a custom pickerview but I would like to use the UIPickerView class methods.

```
#pragma mark - Select Schedule

-(void)selectSchedule:(NSString *)horari :(NSString *)origen :(NSString *)direccio{
    PFQuery *queryParada = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EixBusParades"];
    [queryParada whereKey:@"Parada" equalTo:origen];
    PFQuery *queryHours = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EixBusParades"];
    [queryHours whereKey:@"hSetmana" equalTo:horari];
    PFQuery *queryDireccio = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EixBusParades"];
    [queryDireccio whereKey:@"direccio" equalTo:direccio];
    PFQuery *querySchedule = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryHours,queryParada,queryDireccio]];
    NSArray *objects = [querySchedule findObjects];
    NSArray *depHours = [[objects objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Horaris"];
    // Copy each object from the array depHours to the pickerview array in order to show it
    /*int i;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < [depHours count]; i++) {
        [self.hores objectAtIndex:j] = [depHours objectAtIndex:i];
        j++;
    }*/
}

- (IBAction)tfButton:(id)sender {
    [self.tfHora becomeFirstResponder];
    // Retrieve correct hour data from Parse
    [self selectSchedule:self.tf.text :self.tfOrigen.text :self.tfDireccio.text];
}

- (void)cancelTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{
    // hide the picker view
    [self.tfHora resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)doneTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{
    // hide the picker view
    [self.tfHora resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Initialitzation of the picker view in viewdidload.

```
self.tfHora = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tfHora];
    UIPickerView *pickerHora = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    pickerHora.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerHora.dataSource = self; // Server
    pickerHora.delegate = self;
    self.tfHora.inputView = pickerHora;

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouched:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelTouched:)];

    // the middle button is to make the Done button align to right
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], doneButton, nil]];
    self.tfHora.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Comment: Maybe you could add an observer? Something like if value for picker1 & picker2 were changed , do your parse request

Comment: @LoVo how do I add an observer in order to do this? Should I do the PFQuery in the selector?

Comment: Please, rename your methods: selectSchedule::: is not good. Also where is the code of UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate?

Comment: @Larme I hope this is what you wanted. How should I rename the method?

Comment: You may be interested on how this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493402/show-data-in-uipickerview-second-component-based-on-first-component-selection