# How to reset the values inside the UIPickerView when the other textfield is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have a problem regarding in the UIPickerView. When I select textField1 the UIPickerView is correct but when i click to textField2 the value in pickerData1 is displayed in the UIPickerView instead of the value of pickerData2. Please help me find the bug or correct my wrong code if it is wrong. thanks

**NOTE:** the `bool` in the `didSelectRow` and `titleForRow` function is just a sample. thanks

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!

    let pickerData1 = ["11", "12", "13"]

    let pickerData2 = ["14", "15", "16"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           let picker: UIPickerView
        picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
        picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

        picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

        textField1.inputView = picker
        textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar


       textField2.inputView = picker
       textField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if textfield1selected // just a sample bool
        {
         return pickerData1[row]
        }
        else   // sample bool also
         {
          return pickerData2[row]
         }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

       if textfield1selected // just a sample bool
        {
          textField1.text = pickerData1[row]
        }
        else   // sample bool also
         {
           textField2.text = pickerData2[row]
         }
    }

    func donePicker() {

        textField1.resignFirstResponder()
         textField2.resignFirstResponder()
    }




    }
```

Comment: if my answer help you , kindly accept it .... Thanks Coder are Genius :)

Comment: thank you it really helps hehe ")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

       if textfield1selected // just a sample bool
        {
          textField1.text = pickerData1[row]

          picker.reloadAllComponents();

        }
        else   // sample bool also
         {
           textField2.text = pickerData2[row]
            picker.reloadAllComponents();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Refer this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493402/show-data-in-uipickerview-second-component-based-on-first-component-selection

Comment: sorry but I hardly understand objective c I'm new in swift by the way.